# Avoid using BigInteger

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I have this problem:

f(N) is the last five digits before the trailing zeroes in N!.

ex: 11! = 39916800, f(11) = 99168

ex: 13! = 6227020800, f(13) = 70208

Find f(N) where N is your function input.

And my Solution is:

```
public static String Solving(int n) {

    if (n > 10) {
        String val;
        BigInteger z = BigInteger.ONE;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            z = z.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
        }
        val = String.valueOf(z);
        val = val.substring(n % 10);
        val = val.substring(0, 5);
        return val;
    } else return "";
}
```

How I can avoid use BigInteger?

Comment: You can use `Long`.

Comment: @john It will fail with bigger numbers, for example f(90);

Comment: There is actually no problem described.

Comment: What is wrong with BigInteger then?

Comment: First, factorization all number from 1 -> n, then remove all pair of 2 and 5, then calculate the result modulus 10^5.

Comment: @PhamTrung  I think I did that, but I want to replace bigInteger with another solution, can i do that?

Comment: Everything mod 10^5 will be less than 10^5, is 10^5 inside `int` range? If you already did that, you don't need big int. Your solution don't show what you claimed, I am afraid

Comment: You cannot avoid `BigInteger` *if* you want to factorize n, where n! is large enough not to fit into `int` or `long`. Even if you use `BigInteger` there is a limit for input n.

Comment: @PhamTrung Can you provide an answer please of  your proper way ?

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: @user10548941 updated the answer, there are some bugs previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: thanks  user58697 and  greybeard for excellent suggestion.

First, calculate the number of factor five in all numbers from 1 -> n,

Then remove all pair of 2 and 5,

Finally, calculate the result modulus 10^5.

```
static long mod = 100000;
public static long Solving(int n) {
    int five = 0;
    for (int power5 = 5, count ; 0 < (count = n / power5) ; power5 *= 5){ 
        five += count; 
    }

    // Number of pair (2,5) is the min number between 2 and 5
    int removeFactorTwo = five;
    int removeFactorFive = five;
    long result = 1;
    for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++){
        int st = i;
        while(st % 2 == 0 && removeFactorTwo > 0){
            st /= 2;
            removeFactorTwo--;
        }
        while(st % 5 == 0 && removeFactorFive > 0){
            st /= 5;
            removeFactorFive--;
        }
        result *= st;
        // This will make sure result always <= 10^5
        result %= mod;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't display any result.

Comment: Why not remove `10^k` also?

Comment: @zlakad I dont understand your point? what is the limitation?

Comment: It's maybe worth pointing out that it works because: `(a * b) % n == ((a % n) * b) % n`.

Comment: @PhamTrung May I ask what is the output for `System.out.println(Solving(Integer.MAX_VALUE));`? My PC somehow entered the infinite loop.

Comment: @zlakad For that value, an O(n log n) solution is too slow, so it should be slow.

Comment: No need to count twos: there are always more of them than fives.

Comment: You can't be serious about determining the power of ten to remove. In addition to the [observation by user58697](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49151086/avoid-using-biginteger/49151351#comment85321732_49151351), consider `for (int power5 = 5, count ; 0 < (count = n / power5) ; power5 *= 5)
      five += count;`

Comment: @greybeard love the way you neatly use inclusive-exclusive principle to calculate number of factor of five.